# Excel Sheet Uneditable on certain pages

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am unable to edit a spread sheet. All the cells are locked. If I click on the cell to edit
I get two circles at the bottom the cell. I can Type in that cell but it looks like it is writing over the top of the cell. The work sheet is unprotected. File/Options/advanced shows editing is
allowed. File is not read-only. I can edit the other pages in this file.

[image: note Passenger cell]

Comment: Almost seems like a form control was put there. You might be able to click/hold/drag that around, but I don;t know what that would impact the spreadsheet. Best to ask the person that created the workbook.